# Random Installation Wizard Redirect Magento 1.9.0.1

Tags: magento-community, ce-1.9.0.1, install

I have an install of Magento 1.9.0.1 community edition that is all ready to launch except one problem I continue to run into.  Randomly at different times it will redirect to /index.php/install/.

I have cleared the cache and sessions many times, even restarted the server after clearing the cache and sessions twice as another poster had said worked for him.  But after a short period of time of success, this problem keeps popping up.

I checked to make sure that my local.xml file is there and has the install date in it.  So that checks out just fine.  I compared it to other Magento installs I did (none running 1.9 though as this is my first) and the file looks fine.  Also, I have error and exception logging turned on with nothing being logged on this.

The tricky thing is that it doesn't always do it, but randomly.  I can get around it by just going back to the page I was trying to browse through, but don't want visitors to see this redirect.

There doesn't seem to be a particular category, event, time of day, etc that triggers the redirect more often.  Sometimes I can go 60 minutes without the redirect to install and other times I get the problem a few times a minute.

Any help that anyone can provide is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Moonman. Thanks for the information!  I am running the community edition of Magento, so will that patch work for it and where would I find it?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Reopening per [this discussion in Meta](http://meta.magento.stackexchange.com/questions/533/is-it-possible-to-dispute-the-closure-of-a-question).

Comment: @Moonman67 you can now add your answer as an actual answer

Comment: I am having the exact same problem, with Magento 1.9.1. The install page appears from time to time, like if the app/etc/local.xml file was not readable

Answer (score 6):

> **DISCLAIMER** : All Credit of this answer goes to [@Moonman67](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/12716/moonman67) and I just
>   copied his answer from the question which he pasted to the question by
>   an edit.

This is a real issue.

We had this issue occur in `Magento Enterprise 1.14` running `RedHat` with `PHP 5.3.3` (still occurs in 5.3.28)

It was related to the SOAP API. Hitting any of the SOAP APIs will cause the 404/install redirect behaviour. This is why it appears randomly (if you have something hitting the SOAP API on a periodic schedule)

The cause of the issue was a [***PHP Bug***](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=62577) 
Magento is now aware of this issue and has a patch for it 
(***[PATCH_SUPEE-3762_EE_1.14.0.1_v1.sh](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ee114-later-release-notes)***).